# EmberJs - Update ArrayController content's value

Tags: web-applications, ember.js

I need to know how to get an ArrayController's position of an object in it's content array.
Let's say:

```
App.AnArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.set({
   content: [],
});

App.AnObject = Ember.Object.set({
   name: null,
   lastname: null,
   id: 0
});
```

Now, let's say that i've inserted two AnObject in AnArrayController's content.
How can I update a particular object's value without knowing it's position in the ArrayController, but knowing just that the object's id property is X?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First: Why are you using the set methods?  I would expect your code snippet to be (you need to define your classes first via extend()):

```
 App.AnArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     content: [],
 }); 

App.AnObject = Ember.Object.extend({
   name: null,
   lastname: null,
   id: 0
});
```

If the id is unique you can use the filterProperty. After calling App.initialize(), you can access your controller with the helpt of the router via:

```
var controller = App.router.get("anArrayController");
anObject = controller.findProperty("id", 1); //find Object with id 1
// do something with anObject
```

Comment: My mistake, I'm actually not using the set methods
Anyway, whay i;m trying is to get the arraycontroller's id of an object, just knowing it's id, but NOT it's possition on the array (That's what I need to find out).
So, if I load all arraycontroller's content from server, i can edit any position's data.
Hope I made myself clear. English's not my native language.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand your comment. Maybe you should post a more complete source snippet.